# Regular Expression to match English and Non English characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match a sentence that contains both English and Non English characters but does not contain pure numeric including decimals.

Example - Should match::

```
Renforcé-Bettwäschegar BLUMIRA123
```

Not match::

```
999.99
```

The following code matches everything that's not contained in the ASCII characters -

```
[^\u0000-\u0080]+
```

This is all I have at the moment. Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: So it should match strings which contain at least one English letter ([a-zA-Z]) and one accented/diacritic letter ([àáâäåÀÁÂÃçÇêéëèÊËÉÈïíîìÍÌÎÏñÑöòõóÓÔÕÖÒšŠúüûùÙÚÜÛÿŸýÝžŽ])? Is there a need for non-ASCII characters?

Comment: mtanti - Thanks for your comment. There's no need for non-ASCII characters. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the inputs. The below regex seem to work for me.

```
^([x00-\xFF]+[a-zA-Z][x00-\xFF]+)*
```

Comment: Are you sure? It doesn't look like it will match what you described. This will match any text at the beginning of a line that contains only ASCII characters with one English letter in the middle, not at the beginning or end. The text does not have to contain an accented letter.

Answer (score 2):

See if this works:

```
.*([a-zA-Z].*[àáâäåÀÁÂÃçÇêéëèÊËÉÈïíîìÍÌÎÏñÑöòõóÓÔÕÖÒšŠúüûùÙÚÜÛÿŸýÝžŽ]|[àáâäåÀÁÂÃçÇêéëèÊËÉÈïíîìÍÌÎÏñÑöòõóÓÔÕÖÒšŠúüûùÙÚÜÛÿŸýÝžŽ].*[a-zA-Z]).*
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all I'll assume that you have split your text into sentences. Then try this:

```
!/(?:^| )[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?(?: |$)$/.test(sentence);
```

For example, this is the returned result for each of the below sentences:

```
Renforcé-Bettwäschegar BLUMIRA123 //true
999.99                            //false
Another test                      //true
Hi this is a test 124             //false
Hi this is a test 124.23          //false
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
!/^[0-9.]+$/.test(s)
```

Please note that will match only numbers and decimals, so you need to negate it (the !)

Comment: I think the OP wants both accented and non-accented letters though so just non-accented letters for example wouldn't do.

Comment: `!/^[0-9.]+$/.test("BLUMIRA 123");` will return "true", but since it contains "pure numeric" to quote OP, this is wrong.

Comment: I understood the string must contain only numerals to be wrong