# RegEx: A way to handle both English and non-English characters (and my solution)

Tags: regex, autohotkey

I would like to know if there is a recommendable RegEx pattern to match both English and non-English characters. So far I have come up with [[^\x00-\x7F]+|[a-zA-Z'-]*](https://regex101.com/r/rW9mN0/7) based on the [answer provided at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150033/regular-expression-to-match-non-english-characters/150078#150078). My solutions seems to work but since I am very nice to RegEx I would like to ask you to check this token and suggest some improvements. I am aware of most solutions that touch on this subject like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20683730/regular-expression-to-match-english-and-non-english-characters) but I don't think there is already a good RegEx for this.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depend mostly on the language. But in general, you have to enable the "unicode flag" (this is usually done by prepending `(?u)` to your regex, or by appending `/u`) and use unicode strings. This way, `\w`, `\s` and others will correctly match the corresponding unicode characters.

An example in Python 2 (Python 3 uses unicode by default):

```
>>> re.match('\w', 'è')  # byte string, no unicode flag: no match
>>> re.match('(?u)\w', u'è')  # unicode string and unicode flag: match
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f258bac07e8>
>>> re.match('\w', u'è', re.UNICODE)  # another way to enable the unicode flag
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f258bac0850>
```

Comment: How to use it in regex101.com and in AutoHotKey?

Comment: @menteith: I'm not familiar with regex101 and I don't know what AutoHotKey is, sorry! Try googling "AutoHotKey unicode regex" and, by the way, update your question adding the [tag:autohotkey] tag and stating explicitly that your question is about AutoHotKey (otherwise your question might be closed as off-topic)